# What is a label that can be applied to this stoic quote about banquets?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Remember that you ought to behave in life as you would at a banquet. As something is being passed around it comes to you; stretch out your hand, take a portion of it politely. It passes on; do not detain it. Or it has not come to you yet; do not project your desire to meet it, but wait until it comes in front of you. So act toward children, so toward a wife, so toward office, so toward wealth."

I see this concept coming up a lot in my life, and whenever I want to explain it someone, I can't just recite it, so usually I say something like "Be patient", but there is something about this phrase that dosen't capture all the meaning encapsulated in the original quote.

Comment: I think you're asking for too much.  The quote embodies some rather complex concepts.

Comment: Wait your turn.

Comment: "Don't count your chicken pieces until you hatch a plan to land them on your plate."

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: *Everything in moderation, including moderation.* (O Wilde)

Answer (score 1):

An anecdote’s ability to convey meaning through metaphorical examples, via fictional or nonfictional means,  is what distinguishes a proverb from a cliché. I think the statement which sums this particular excerpt best lies somewhere between “What goes around, comes around,” and “All good things come to those who wait.”

> [**what goes round comes
> round**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what%20goes%20round%20comes%20round)
> **idiom**
> *chiefly British, informal*
> —used to say that if someone treats other people badly he or she will eventually be treated badly by someone else
> // *You should not mistreat them. What goes round comes round.*

Still don’t think I’ve answered the question, but hopefully it helps?

Comment: Hi Penny, welcome to EL&U, and thanks for your answer. However, what we're particularly looking for is *authoritative* answers (i.e. supported by evidence, so as to distinguish them from mere personal opinion, guesswork etc). Your answer would be much improved if you [edit] it to add a quoted explanation for each of the two expressions, preferably linked to each source. :-)

Comment: I've added one dictionary reference so you can see what it looks like. Why not try adding a reference for the 2nd expression? Formatting can be a bit tricky, but do your best; one tip is to put two blank spaces at the end of a line to make it non-breaking. For links, put the text in [] followed by the link in (), eg `[text](url)`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious: "Be **stoical**"

OED

> **stoical**
>
> **2.b.** *Of a person*: **Resembling a Stoic in austerity, indifference to pleasure and pain, repression of all feeling, and the like.**
>
> 1589   T. Nashe Anat. Absurditie sig. Bv   *Antient antiquitie was woont to bee such a stoycall obseruer of continencie, that women were not permitted so much as to kisse their Kinsmen.*
>
> 1849   T. B. Macaulay Hist. Eng. II. vii. 170   *He was a different man from the reserved and stoical William whom the multitude supposed to be destitute of human feelings.*
>
> 1855   W. H. Prescott Hist. Reign Philip II of Spain I. i. i. 7   *Every one, even the most stoical, was touched by this..scene.*